# Sending a request to a docker container running in GCP VM

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, prerender

I have a prerender server running in a docker container on my GCP VM instance running on Debian. I know it is running from the docker logs on the containers' port 3000. But I can't seem to send a request to the VM external IP. The firewall settings on the VM instance allow for both HTTP and HTTPS traffic but nothing seems to happen. I am using the VM cloud shell to ssh into the VM so I am positive the container itself is running as it should but I believe the issue lies somewhere between the VM and the container as I seem to have no activity on my VM network.

What I've tried so far:
the obvious first try was to simply send a request from a browser to that external IP address, this was just a simple `http://'externalIPofVM'/render?fullpage=true&renderType=jpeg&url='requestedURL'` I know from local testing that this works I just can't seem to figure out how to send this to my docker on the VM. Even if that request failed on the prerender server I'd at least know that it's hitting the docker in the first place but at the moment it's never being hit.

I believe it may have something to do with connecting the VM to the container but I don't know? This is my first dive into running a container on a VM so any information I may have left out please tell me and I'll happily provide as much detail as possible.
[example output of a successful prerender request on a local container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iNQA.png)

the image is the type of response I expect from a successful request to prerender, however even a failed one would be helpful at this point as I'd at least know I'm making contact.

Comment: First of all, make sure you have exposed that port for 0.0.0.0/0 CIDR. What the ‘docker ps’ command shows?

Comment: CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
8f1d737bdc2b   eefb9b8df26d   "entrypoint.sh npm s…"   5 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp   vigorous_pasteur

this is the output from the docker ps command

Comment: the 0.0.0.0/0 CIDR was the absolute answer. Everything is working as intended now thank you!